# How can I prevent my emails from being flagged as spam?

Tags: php

My emails are being flagged as spam. How can I prevent this? Here's how I'm sending them:

```
public function sendMail($to,$subject,$from,$headers)
{
    $headers .= "From: ".$from. "<support@mydomain.com>";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";           
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: smail-PHP ".phpversion()."\r\n"; 

    $message .= $this->getMessage();

    return mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);    
}
```

Comment: Don't you see a half dozen questions with similar titles over in the **Related** sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

You can partially control it, add `headers` in correct format..use swiftmail or other apart from php `mail()` some mail servers feel bad if send via php `mail()`

Check for any blacklisting as well from mail servers.

Always test it on live wires, check FILTERS if you are using `Yahoo`.